# How to pass a parameter in a parametrized test to a decorator?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, decorator

I have a decorator that checks the response of api methods and there is a test that I want to make paramitrized

In the example below, I removed the extra code, but the essence has not changed

```
def check_api_response(api_method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        request_to_api = api_method(*args, **kwargs)
        assert request.status_code == 200
        return response
    return wrapper


class TestCatalogs:
    @check_api_response
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('car_type', [1, 2, 3, 4])
    def test_car_type(self, car_type):
        catalog = catalogs_get(car_type).json()
        assert catalog['type'] != ''
```

I get a function in args, kwargs is empty

```
args = (<API.test_oem_api.TestCatalogs object at 0x0000019D1BB51EE0>,)
kwargs = {}
```

I seem to be missing something and doing it wrong

Comment: `response` isn't defined in `wrapper`; did you mean to say `response = api_method(...)`?

Comment: Also, you are decorating your test, not the (presumed) API request method (`catalogs_get`) that the test calls.

Comment: Thank you, if I transfer the decorator to the catalogs _get method, then everything works, but this method is used in other places in the code and I thought you can bind the decorator to the test in which this method is called